# How to trigger observer on child element when nested in dom-if Polymer

Tags: data-binding, polymer, dom-if

I am trying to retrieve updated data in a child Polymer element, but the data stays bound to the initialized value.

**PARENT**

```
<template is="dom-if" if="[[items.0]]">
  <child-el id="id_0" id-item="[[items.0.idItem]]"></child-el>
</template>

...

_updateChild () {
  if (this.items[0]) {
    this.shadowRoot.getElementById('id_0').idItem = this.items[0].idItem;
    this.shadowRoot.getElementById('id_0').idItem.notifyPath;
  }
}
```

**CHILD**

```
<iron-ajax id="ajax"
  handle-as="json"
  last-response="{{data}}"
  method="get"
  on-error="_onError"
  url="https://api.com/item-price">
</iron-ajax>

<div>
  <p id="price">[[price(data.price)]]</p>
</div>

...

static get properties() {
  return {
    idItem: { type: String, observer: 'getResponse' }
  }
}

getResponse() {
  let request = this.$.ajax.generateRequest();
  request.completes.then(req => {
    this.idItem = null;
  })
}

price(amt) {
  return amt
}
```

Update pricing executes, but when `idItem` is set, but the observer on `idItem` "`getResponse()`" doesn't execute and bind to `data.price`.

How can I get these events to cascade properly so each time `items.0.idItem` changes the binding on the `child-eel` `this.data.price` gets updated?

Answer (score 0):

How is the items.0.idItem changed?

Try changing the idItem like this `this.set('items.0.idItem', 100)`

Comment: Is it `this.shadowRoot.getElementById('id_0').set('items.0.idItem', 100)`?

Comment: This.set () is used to notify a change in an attribute, the object or object in an array.

https://polymer-library.polymer-project.org/3.0/docs/devguide/model-data#set-path

Comment: How is the id-item changed? Do you receive a new list of items?

I believe the problem could be this, the observer getResponse is not called because the child did not 'receive' the change to the idItem

Comment: I don't know if that would be the case, but you could do a 'mock test'. Create a function to change the idItem, inside the function add:   this.set ('items.0.idItem', 100);   Here 100 is the new test value for the idItem. When calling this function (can be by a button), you will check if getResponse was called inside the child

Comment: There is a grand-parent element that is bound like `<browse-compare id="compare" items="[[itemsToCompare]]"></browse-compare>` that is set with an AJAX response like `this.set('itemsToCompare.0', e.detail.item)` etc...

Answer (score 0):

Generally it is bad to re trigger something other than view with `dom-if` unless you don't use `restamp` attribute on it (https://polymer-library.polymer-project.org/3.0/api/elements/dom-if#DomIf-property-restamp)

Your approach seems a little tricky, because after request is completed, you change observed property to `null`

```
getResponse() {
  let request = this.$.ajax.generateRequest();
  request.completes.then(req => {
    this.idItem = null;
  })
}
```

Changing it to null should result to re trigger observer **again**. But what will happen, is you just listen callback again, without re-triggering **ajax request**.

`iron-ajax` has method called `generateRequest()`, you probably should use it, if you don't have `auto` attribute set to `iron-ajax` component and don't change params of this component (see https://www.webcomponents.org/element/@polymer/iron-ajax/elements/iron-ajax#property-auto)